# When i click on a website to enter it,it enters but the problem is a file is downloaded automatically

Tags: windows, google-chrome, download, filesystems, malware

Once I click on a site this window appears and download the file without my permission.**Note:** I use Chrome as a browser and Neat Download Manager
[here is what happens[and this What in the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy4XM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3FwJ.png)

I tried to search for a solution in my download manager and **I found this link in downloading details** https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/js/car.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like your browser is initiating automatic downloads when you access certain websites, which can be quite concerning. The link you provided points to a JavaScript file typically associated with ad services, which shouldn't usually trigger a download. Let's address the issue step by step.

1. **Run a Malware Scan:** Use trusted antivirus software to rule out malware.
2. **Disable Chrome Extensions:** Go to `chrome://extensions/` and disable all extensions. If this stops the downloads, re-enable them one by one to find the culprit.
3. **Clear Cache and Cookies:** Clear browsing data via `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`.
4. **Adjust Chrome Settings:** Set Chrome to ask for permission before downloading multiple files at `chrome://settings/content/automaticDownloads`.
5. **Update Chrome:** Ensure you're running the latest version at `chrome://settings/help`.
6. **Check Download Manager:** Review settings in Neat Download Manager for any automatic download triggers.
7. **Incognito Mode Test:** Use `Ctrl+Shift+N` to open an Incognito window and visit the website to see if the issue persists.

Remember, do not open the automatically downloaded files if their safety is uncertain, and keep your data backed up.

If you've followed these steps and the issue continues, please provide additional details such as whether the problem occurs on all websites or specific ones and any patterns you've noticed.